# Richness of probability space that supports a sequence of i.i.d. normal variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, that supports a sequence $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of independent standard normal random variables.

Is there always another standard normal random variable $\eta$ defined on the same probability space, such that $\eta$ and $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $\Omega=(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, with the “uniform probability”. The $\xi_i$ are such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\xi_i(\omega)}{(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2}dx}=\omega_i$. Then $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\xi_i, i \geq 1)$ and thus any random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ independent from $(\xi_i)_i$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}$ so is constant.

Comment: Thanks! Your argument even shows that given any probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ like in the question we just have to set $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(\xi_i, i \in \mathbb{N})$ and then consider $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$, doesn't it?